# Quasar pwa service-worker

Tags: vuejs3, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm trying to configure a service worker, but errors are popping up.

I use quasar dev - pwa

I use this configuration

```
pwa: {
    workboxMode: 'injectManifest', // or 'injectManifest' //generateSW
    swFilename: 'src-pwa/custom-service-worker.ts',
    injectPwaMetaTags: true,
    manifestFilename: 'manifest.json'
    // useCredentialsForManifestTag: false
    // useFilenameHashes: true,
    // extendGenerateSWOptions (cfg) {}
    // extendInjectManifestOptions (cfg) {},
    // extendManifestJson (json) {}
    // extendPWACustomSWConf (esbuildConf) {}
  }
```

The file structure is like this
[src-pwa directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjrqb.png)

but it gives an error

```
Error during service worker registration: Error: Expected /src-pwa/custom-service-worker.ts to have javascript content-type, but received video/mp2t
    at index.js:116:23
```

register-service-worker file

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker';

register(process.env.SERVICE_WORKER_FILE, {
  // registrationOptions: { scope: './' },

  ready(/* registration */) {
    console.log('Service worker is active.');
  },

  registered(/* registration */) {
    console.log('Service worker has been registered.');
  },

  cached(/* registration */) {
    // console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
  },

  updatefound(/* registration */) {
    // console.log('New content is downloading.')
  },

  updated(/* registration */) {
    // console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
  },

  offline() {
    // console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
  },

  error(err) {
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', err);
  }
});
```

custom-service-worker file

```
declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope &
  typeof globalThis & { skipWaiting: () => void };

import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import {
  precacheAndRoute,
  cleanupOutdatedCaches,
  createHandlerBoundToURL
} from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute, NavigationRoute } from 'workbox-routing';

self.skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();

// Use with precache injection
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

cleanupOutdatedCaches();

// Non-SSR fallback to index.html
// Production SSR fallback to offline.html (except for dev)
if (process.env.MODE !== 'ssr' || process.env.PROD) {
  registerRoute(
    new NavigationRoute(
      createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PWA_FALLBACK_HTML),
      { denylist: [/sw\.js$/, /workbox-(.)*\.js$/] }
    )
  );
}
```

I don’t even know where to dig anymore. If I delete it swFilename: 'src-pwa/custom-service-worker.ts', then it’s an error

```
Uncaught non-precached-url: createHandlerBoundToURL('index.html') was called, but that URL is not precached. Please pass in a URL that is precached instead.
    at PrecacheController.createHandlerBoundToURL (http://localhost:9200/sw.js:1175:15)
    at createHandlerBoundToURL (http://localhost:9200/sw.js:1655:32)
    at http://localhost:9200/sw.js:1725:9
    at http://localhost:9200/sw.js:1730:3
```

Comment: the error sounds like something is wrong with the file being typescript. Maybe the file isn't being transpiled? First try without typescript and write the service worker in just JS

Comment: It is standard file from directory src-pwa

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Quasar PWA Documentation](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-pwa/configuring-pwa#quasar-config-file), the config option `swFilename` is the **generated** service worker filename for production, **not** the name of the dev file. As the comment next to the option also states:

> should be .js (as it's the distribution file, not the input file)

Your swFilename value however has the .ts extension and also includes src path.

It should not be a path, but a single name with .js extension.

The default value automatically given by the Quasar framework `sw.js` would suffice.

```js
pwa: {
    workboxMode: 'injectManifest', // or 'injectManifest' //generateSW
    swFilename: 'sw.js',
    injectPwaMetaTags: true,
    manifestFilename: 'manifest.json'
    // useCredentialsForManifestTag: false
    // useFilenameHashes: true,
    // extendGenerateSWOptions (cfg) {}
    // extendInjectManifestOptions (cfg) {},
    // extendManifestJson (json) {}
    // extendPWACustomSWConf (esbuildConf) {}
  }
```